# schema exception when encoding is set to utf-16

Tags: c#, xsd

I have a xml schema file that starts with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

When i try to add this schema file into XmlDocument instance Schemas collection, I get following exception

> There is no Unicode byte order mark. Cannot switch to Unicode.

If I change encoding to UTF-8, the API works fine. Anyway of using this sceham with utf-16?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a valid XML file if it's UTF-16 but there's no BOM. From the [W3C XML 1.0 recommendation, 5th edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charencoding):

> Entities encoded in UTF-16 **must** and entities encoded in UTF-8 may begin with the Byte Order Mark described by Annex H of [ISO/IEC 10646:2000], section 16.8 of [Unicode] (the ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE character, #xFEFF). This is an encoding signature, not part of either the markup or the character data of the XML document. XML processors must be able to use this character to differentiate between UTF-8 and UTF-16 encoded documents.

Basically, it's fine for it to be in UTF-16, but you'll need a byte order mark. Or use UTF-8 in the first place, of course...

Comment: How can I add and use a byte order mark here? I read about this been the first character but when try adding it, had no luck reading the xml programatically. Any ideas what i may be missing? Any exaples will help.

Comment: @imak: The file should already *have* one if it's in UTF-16... otherwise it's not a valid XML file. However, if it doesn't you may be able to load it into a text editor and ask that to explicitly save with a BOM. If absolutely necessary you could read it all into a string using File.ReadAllText and write it out again using File.WriteAllText and an instance of UnicodeEncoding with the BOM flag set.